# Make one click filtering available in jobs

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, stack-overflow-jobs

Filtering in jobs doesn't seem trival to me.  You have to click the little setup cog wheel thingy, tab over to the item you want, select value and click a button to update your search.

I am fine with keeping it this way but we also have a lot of room on the left side of the site for quick filtering.  Can we please add a way to quickly filter your initial job list by presenting users a one click methodology?

Here you can show certain filters and actually counts next to each item.  I forgot to place the counts on the experience section but you get the idea.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I think — and I know you'll correct me if I'm wrong — you're stating the problem, "It takes too many clicks and/or keystrokes to run the job search I want."  We agree.  So, we're looking at some UI improvements to help.  There are some forthcoming A/B tests to see, for instance, whether providing a dropdown list of developer roles to click when focusing on the search box will help anyone.  ("Developer roles" here mean things like "Front-end Developer," which we already determine for most or all jobs but don't really surface.)

Now, as to your proposed solution, we may not go in this *exact* direction.  For one thing, a surprising number of users are not on wide-screen monitors and, therefore, don't really have the space on the left.  (We're reminded of this tragic fact every time we do a round of user testing, it seems.)  I know there are ways to manage that issue, but there are other design and performance considerations involved too.

In summary: we'll be working on UI improvements to job search, but not necessarily this *exact* one.

Comment: You may be interested in this thing called "responsive design". You don't have to design for every screen resolution, and you can even do some really neat tricks with [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) so you can have completely different layouts, some optimized for larger screens -- say, by providing more options in what would be blank space -- and some for smaller ones, by, say, collapsing those into a dropdown. In other words, "some users have small screens" isn't an excuse.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes We are aware of responsive design, thanks.  That doesn't mean we frequently _use_ it, as such, but we know it's a solution to some design problems.  Perhaps I should have emphasized "there are other design and performance considerations."

Comment: Actually, more detail would be nice. Just about the only thing I can think of is bandwidth, and the addition for media queries, at least from my view from the outside, is tiny next to the amount already used. An `@media (max-width: 1000px) { .extraDetails { display: none; } }` is way less than just about any question on this site, especially the long ones we encourage; that's before any minifying. What other concerns are there? Also, apologies for being snippy earlier. I'm frustrated because you say "because small screens", but on half of a 1080p screen, the site's still oversized.

Comment: For what it's worth I a) often have to set my phone to desktop mode to find job options, and b) prefer to use my phone in desktop mode anyway.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes you might be interessting in supporting this [old feature request from '09](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5070/can-so-have-a-fluid-vs-fixed-width-layout), or just wait another 6-8 years.